# jQuery find td with class name and change the text

Tags: jquery, replace, find

I'm trying to use jquery to find a text based on it's class name and change it. Basically I have this structure:

```
<td class="walletBalance">0.0000 XBT</td>
```

So, im trying:

```
$("tbody").find("tr").each(function() { //get all rows in table
var ratingTd = $(this).find('td.walletBalance’);//Refers to TD element
if (ratingTd.text() == “0.0000 XBT”) {
    ratingTd.text(’changed text’);
}
});
```

What im doing wrong?

[For more understanding html structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQeea.png)

[Specifically what value i'm trying to change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovEBT.png)

PS: Im using tampermonkey

```
    // ==UserScript==
// @name         testingalarm
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.hey
// @grant        none
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...
    $("tbody").find("tr").each(function() {
  var ratingTd = $(this).find('td.walletBalance');
  if (ratingTd.text() == "0.0000 XBT") {
    ratingTd.text('changed text');
  }
});
})();
```

Btw, this alarm is working:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         testingalarm
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.some
// @grant        none
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...
    $(document).ready(function() {
  alert('WINNING');
});
})();
```

PSS: after Manaren answer

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         aaaaa
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.some
// @grant        none
// @require http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // Your code here...
    $("tbody tr td.walletBalance").each(
        function(){
            if ($(this).text() == "0.0000 XBT"){
                $(this).text("changed text");
            }
        }
    );
})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try this, i tested it in browser and it works correctly.

```
$("tbody tr td.walletBalance").each(
        function(){
            if ($(this).text() == "0.0000 XBT"){
                $(this).text("changed text"); 
            }
        }
    );
```

Issues:

- Wrong quotes characters
- Imo too complex code for so simple task
- Maybe some issues with import

Comment: Changed quotes and added as u said. Still nothing.

Comment: And in which moment do you execute your code? Is it after properly loading HTML? Like you did in alert example. Otherwise wrap this code in window.onload or similar.

Comment: Actually, i have got this alarm before page loads properly. Should i use setTimeout then?

Comment: Better than setTimeout wil be $(document).ready( "that piece of code" )

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you're using invalid single and double quote characters. Single quotes should be `'`, not `’`, and double quotes need to be `"`, not `“` or `”`. Once that is fixed your code works fine:

```js
$("tbody").find("tr").each(function() {
  var ratingTd = $(this).find('td.walletBalance');
  if (ratingTd.text() == "0.0000 XBT") {
    ratingTd.text('changed text');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="walletBalance">0.0000 XBT</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can u look at tampermoney script please. I changed that way and still nothing.

Comment: Added an example of working alarm using this script

Comment: no. Maybe i should print something in console for better understanding a problem.